# Can induction go through metal with holes?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I intend to use (Qi) wireless charging for a project of mine. It uses induction coils to transfer power wirelessly.

In my project, between the coils there will be a 1.5mm sheet of brass. The first question I had is if this would work. I tried using a 3mm copper sheet that I have, and sure enough the answer is negative, the sheet absorbs the EM fields.

But what if I made holes in the sheet? Would some of the field penetrate then? Would it be proportional to the size and "density" of the holes? Or would the conductor still absorb the fields?

Comment: It would be good to be more quantitative. How much did the copper sheet attenuate the signal pickup?